# css transition doesn't work if element start hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 `div`s, one of them is hidden via `display:none;`. Both have the same css transition on the property `right`.

If I change the property `right` through JQuery and show the hidden `div`, either by using `$.css('display','none')` or `$.show()` or `$.toggle()` etc., the hidden div draw instantly at the ending position

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').show();
  $('.b').css('right','80%');
  $('.a').css('right','80%');
})
```

```css
body {
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
}

div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:5%;
  top:0;
  transition:right .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  color: white;
}

.a {
  display:block;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>A
</div>
<div class='b'>B
</div>
<button>Launch</button>
```

If I use `$.animate()` it will work. But my question is ; Is that a bug or a normal behavior?

**Edit** Not a duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property) cause the problem here is not about animating the display property nor the visibility

Comment: normal behavior, you need a slight delay between the display and changing the right

Comment: I was about to say "ok", but what do you call a normal behavior here? Something that doesn't work can't be a normal behavior right? It's just a bug, a well known bug, I can understand that and I'll deal with it, but still a bug, no?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. How can I deny this?

Comment: it's not a bug but it's how it should work ... and yes it's not a duplicate. I don't have the needed words to explain it but someone else will come and better explain

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/r7016skg/ adding a small delay will output what you expect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To understand plainly the situation, you need to understand the relation between  the CSSOM and the DOM.

In a [previous Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342730/javascript-are-dom-redraw-methods-synchronous/47343090#47343090), I developed a bit on how the *redraw* process works.
Basically, there are three steps, DOM manipulation, reflow, and paint.

- The first (*DOM manipulation*) is just modifying a js object, and is all synchronous.
- The second (*reflow*, a.k.a *layout*) is the one we are interested in, and a bit more complex, since only some DOM methods and the paint operation need it. It consists in updating all the CSS rules and recalculating all the computed styles of every elements on the page.
  Being a quite complex operation, browsers will try to do it as rarely as possible.
- The third (*paint*) is only done 60 times per seconds at max (only when needed).

---

CSS transitions work by transitioning from a state to an other one. And to do so, they look at the *last computed value* of your element to create the initial state.
Since browsers do recalculate the computed styles only when required, at the time your transition begins, none of the DOM manipulations you applied are effective yet.

So in your first scenario, when the transition's initial state is calculated we have

```
.b { computedStyle: {display: none} }
```

... and that's it.

Because, yes, that's how powerful `display: none` is for the CSSOM; if an element has `display: none`, then it doesn't need to be painted, it doesn't exist.

So I'm not even sure the transition algorithm will kick in, but even if it did, the initial state would have been invalid for **any** transitionable value, since all computed values are just null.

Your `.a` element being visible since the beginning doesn't have this issue and can be transitioned.

And if you are able to make it work with a delay (induced by `$.animate`), it's because between the DOM manip' that did change the `display` property and the execution of this delayed DOM manip' that does trigger the transition, the browser did trigger a *reflow* (e.g because the screen v-sync kicked in between and that the *paint* operation fired).

---

Now, it is not part of the question, but since we do understand better what happens, we can also **control it better**.

Indeed, [some DOM methods](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) do need to have up-to-date computed values. For instance `Element.getBoundingClientRect`, or `element.offsetHeight` or `getComputedStyle(element).height` etc. All these need **the entire page** to have updated computed values so that the boxing are made correctly (for instance an element could have a margin pushing it more or less, etc.).

This means that we don't have to be in the unknown of when the browser will trigger this *reflow*, we can force it to do it when we want.

But remember, **all the elements on the page** needs to be updated, this is not a small operation, and if browsers are lenient to do it, there is a good reason.

So better use it sporadically, at most once per frame.

Luckily, the Web APIs have given us the ability to hook some js code just before this paint operation occurs: [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

So the best is to force our reflow only once in this pre-paint callback, and to call everything that needs the updated values from this callback.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').show(); // apply display:block synchronously
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => { // wait just before the next paint
    document.body.offsetHeight; // force a reflow
    // trigger the transitions
    $('.b').css('right','80%');
    $('.a').css('right','80%');
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
}

div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:5%;
  top:0;
  transition:right .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  color: white;
}

.a {
  display:block;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>A
</div>
<div class='b'>B
</div>
<button>Launch</button>
```

But to be honest, it's not always easy to set up, so if you are sure it is something that will get fired sporadically, you may be lazy and do it all synchronously:

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').show(); // apply display:block
  document.body.offsetHeight; // force a reflow
  // trigger the transitions
  $('.b').css('right','80%');
  $('.a').css('right','80%');
})
```

```css
body {
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
}

div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:5%;
  top:0;
  transition:right .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  color: white;
}

.a {
  display:block;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>A
</div>
<div class='b'>B
</div>
<button>Launch</button>
```

Comment: Ok, I mark this as best. This is very instructive, thank you! If I understand correctly both what you explained and the jquery doc for `$.show()`, the @yunzen is correct because calling `$.show()` as an animation will trigger a reflow at the end right? (`$.show(0)`)

Comment: @vincent-d I couldn't get my head clearly on what happens in jQuery sources when duration is `0`, but yes, there must be something there that does trigger a reflow. If you have more time than myself to make the walkthrough, the entrance [is here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/effects.js#L633).

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you again that was very instructive and interesting. I'm reading jquery to figure this out, if I find, I'll tell you. Any way, what is sure is there's a reflow when you use  `$.show()` passing params throught it, because of this comment `Set the display of the elements in a second loop to avoid constant reflow` So what I'm looking at are the globals and I found `ownerDocument()` and `appendChild()`but I can't find them in the list you provided here https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: Oh, and the appenChild() come imediatly with a `removeChild()`. That happens each time you call `show()` but not if you put no param because it will just juggling with the display property (and apparently that avoid the reflow)

Comment: @Kaiido Maybe my javascript knowledge is a little poor, so tell me if that may be the reason of the reflow :D

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `show()` without a parameter basically does this

```
$('.b').css('display', 'block');
```

So what you are doing is this

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').css('display', 'block');
  $('.b').css('right','80%');
  $('.a').css('right','80%');
})
```

which is basically the same as

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').css({
    'display': 'block',
    'right': '80%'
  });
  $('.a').css('right','80%');
})
```

**But you can't transition anything, if the display is changed at the same time.**

Adding a duration value to the `show()` call, does something more complex than just changing the `display`. It will add the element to an animation queue like this

```
$('.b').css({
  'display': 'block', 
  'overflow': 'hidden',
  'height': '0',
  'width': '0',
  'margin': '0',
  'width': '0',
  'opacity': '0'
});
$('.b').animate({
  height: '50px',
  padding: '0px',
  margin: '0px', 
  width: '50px', 
  opacity: '1'
}, 0)
```

So what you need to do is putting the duration value of `0` (zero) into the `show()` call as a parameter

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').show(0);
  $('.b').css('right','80%');
  $('.a').css('right','80%');
})
```

```css
body {
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
}

div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:5%;
  top:0;
  transition:right .5s .1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  color: white;
}

.a {
  display:block;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>A
</div>
<div class='b'>B
</div>
<button>Launch</button>
```

Comment: from the Doc: `The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ),` http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: by adding a number you make it animated and fix the issue (any number will work, even higher than 0)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's what the doc says. It also says the default duration is `400` . I'm confused

Comment: there is different call of the method ... with and without argument. the on without is not animated and the one with argument is animated ... and the animated one is fixing the issue

Comment: This is weird yes, but the result is perfect. Before I came back here (I thought my post was lost forever lol) I came up with the show() callback. And yes, it does apply the 400ms as @TemaniAfif explained. So I validate this solution since it's the best imho

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would check to see if the element is visible after making it show. Then continue on through the jQuery.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/789su6xb/

```
$('button').on('click',function(){

    var b = $('.b');
    b.show();

    if(b.is(":visible")) {
        $('.b').css('right','80%');
        $('.a').css('right','80%');
    }

});
```

Comment: Please explain your down vote. This is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I understand why. I said I don't want to use $.animate and let the css transition do his job, so if I don't want that, I don't either want a solution where I have to check the dom status

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Everyone is getting downvotes for providing improved code to what you currently use. You ask if it is normal behavior, yes. Your code just needs to be written like one of our answers. You need to state that the show is instant. Provide a delay. Or check if your element is visible.

Comment: How my question is unclear? Also, check the validate answer, this is a good answer because it's a solution to the problem, not a sneaky way to get a similar "good enough" result.

Comment: I don't know why you get a downvote, you don't derserve it, still your answer is not good enough to be the good one, and I told you why. The others get downvotes because they answers are totaly 100% off-topic

Comment: Very kind. I still don't understand what you're asking, haha. Have you received an answer to your question now?

Comment: Yes, you don't see it? Basicaly, when you change the display of an element, at the very same time you do it you can't do any transitions on that element. `$.show()` method have multiple call status, one of them is an animation itself, that's what we need to fix the "native" behavior I just explained (display vs other anim) so we simply set a duration to $.show() to get that call, by doing `$.show(0)`

Comment: Agreed. Bless you for sticking at this awkward question. God speed!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with starting a transition on show is the same issue as trying to start a transition on load. It's really annoying that CSS doesn't support starting an animation on the same frame that an element shows. See the answer here: [css3 transition animation on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load)

The solution is to use keyframes instead of transition. But then you can't do a variable right, it's hard coded at 80% in the CSS file.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').show();
  $('.b').addClass('goLeft');
  $('.a').addClass('goLeft');
})
```

```css
body {
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
}

div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:5%;
  top:0;
  color: white;
}

.goLeft {
  animation-name: goLeft;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.a {
  display:block;
  top:60px;
}

@keyframes goLeft {
  from {
    right: 5%;
  }
  to {
    right: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>A
</div>
<div class='b'>B
</div>
<button>Launch</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this fiddle Just need to add a timeout

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.b').show();
  setTimeout(function(){ $('.b').css('right','80%');
  $('.a').css('right','80%'); }, 0);
  
})
```

```css
body {
  width:800px;
  height:800px;
}

div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#333;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  right:5%;
  top:0;
  transition:right .5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.a {
  display:block;
  top:20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>
</div>
<div class='b'>
</div>
<button>Launch</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qu2pybch/

Comment: Can't you paste the codepen contents from there to a snippet here?

Comment: @yunzen thanks for the suggestion will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: You can make a full working snippet in here to. I did that for you

Comment: Thanks.
looks neat