# requestAnimationFrame appears to be invalid

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-loop, requestanimationframe

I watched Jake Archibald's talk recently. He gave an example in his speech where he says to use requestAnimationFrame twice to delay applying a CSS style to perform a CSS animation.

See https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1337

I reproduced the example to test it, but without luck:

## The box will move directly to a position of 500px, instead of going from 1000px to 500px.

Jake Archibald's a solution was proposed. use a two-layer nested requestAnimationFrame

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work for me. Why?

Here is the code snippet that *should* work but **doesn't**:

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");
box.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
  box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-out';
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        box.style.transform = 'translateX(250px)';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">box</div>
```

Comment: can you specify the link of the speech?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: I actually see you problem. Can you approve the edit I've done to your question? That might allow other people to better understand the question and answer.

Comment: Hey @Kaiido, I guess is a matter of browser version. Your example moves to the right after the click, whereas it's expected to go left. (Chrome 80.0.3987.132 and Firefox 73.0.1) Where are you testing it?

Comment: Your code snippet appears to work on both Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: Following his explanation, I think the code might actually have an error. `box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-out';` should be inside the `rAF` callback, otherwise the element is already in an animated state (on it's way from 0 to 1000px), and the browser might (this is my guess) simply *collapse* those instructions. As in, *"oh, you're already animating, and are at position X, but now the final position has changed, well then just go to there..."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");
box.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-out';
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        box.style.transform = 'translateX(250px)';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really hate videos so I didn't checked it entirely, but certainly they already had that `#box` element translated before they call that javascript.

If they didn't then it would actually perform the transition from `translateX(0)` to `translateX(1000px)` during one frame, and right after transition from wherever it was (probably not far from begining left) to `translateX(250px)`.

So for a fix, you can set the initial `translateX` value in CSS.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");
box.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';
  box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-out';
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        box.style.transform = 'translateX(250px)';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(1000px);
}
```

```html
You have to scroll to the right now.
<div id="box">box</div>
```

Now, you should really not use that double requestAnimationFrame hack. Instead [identify the problem and use a proper fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134528/css-transition-doesnt-start-callback-isnt-called/55137322#55137322) (i.e force a reflow).

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");
box.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(500px)';

  box.offsetWidth; // force reflow so our box is translated to initial position
  box.style.transition = 'transform 1s ease-out';
  box.style.transform = 'translateX(250px)';
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">box</div>
```