# Why is window.requestAnimationFrame not working immediately after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, requestanimationframe

In a project I'm coding, I am using window.requestAnimationFrame in order to make an animation repeat each time a button is clicked. I'm very confused though because after I refresh the page, if I click the button two times, the second time the animation doesn't happen. It only works on the second time if I click something else on the page before clicking the button, but if I click it immediately after refreshing, it doesn't. Here's some of the code from the button when it is clicked, but if you need more code, I can provide it. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
submitNewPlunderForm.onclick = () => {
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.users);
    let username = newPlunderFormUsername.value;
    if (users[username] === undefined) {
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.border = "1.5px solid #eb3a34";
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.boxShadow = "none";
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.transition = "none"; 
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            newPlunderFormUsername.style.transition = "box-shadow 200ms";
            newPlunderFormUsername.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px #eb3a34"; 
        });
```

Comment: I doubt you would get an animation frame after submitting a form, and possibly "clicking the first time" is just giving the page time to reload from the server. More information about  [how to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including some HTML would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first rAF callback fires after page load varies a lot across implementations, and there isn't really any specs about this, the Document has to be *fully active* before the callbacks can fire, but browsers can add whatever delay they want.
From memory, in Firefox it may take about 20ms after the call to `requestAnimationFrame` even with a 60FPS monitor (that is it waits about two frames), while on Chrome it may happen almost synchronously.

Also, most modern browsers do throttle click events to the animated-frames rate, so your two calls may happen in the same event-loop frame, before the browser triggers any reflow.
Finally, [Chrome is very buggy](https://crbug.com/919408).

But anyway, for what you are doing, you don't need rAF at all, just [trigger a reflow synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134528/css-transition-doesnt-start-callback-isnt-called/55137322#55137322):

```js
submitNewPlunderForm.onclick = () => {
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.users);
    let username = newPlunderFormUsername.value;
    if (users[username] === undefined) {
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.border = "1.5px solid #eb3a34";
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.boxShadow = "none";
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.transition = "box-shadow 200ms";
        newPlunderFormUsername.offsetWidth; // force reflow
        newPlunderFormUsername.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px #eb3a34";
    }
});
```

```js
const newPlunderFormUsername = document.createElement("input");
document.body.append(newPlunderFormUsername);
newPlunderFormUsername.style.boxShadow = "none";
newPlunderFormUsername.style.transition = "box-shadow 2000ms";
newPlunderFormUsername.offsetWidth; // force reflow
newPlunderFormUsername.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px #eb3a34";
```