# How can I remove a class without triggering a CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a website in which there are some simple CSS animations:

1. `fade-in`: Causes the element to fade into view, and
2. `error`: Causes the element to turn red and shake for a brief moment.

When I trigger the `error` animation through JS, once it's done, the `fade-in` animation plays as well, which is not desired. Here's the CSS and JS:

style.css:

```css
...

/* All children of the `splash` class are subject to the `fade-in` animation */

.splash * {
    animation: fade-in 1s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}


@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.error {
    animation: shake 0.4s ease-in-out;
    border-color: red;
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    25% { transform: translateX(-5px); }
    50% { transform: translateX(5px); }
    75% { transform: translateX(-5px); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}

.no_transition {
    animation: none;
    transition: none;
}

...
```

script.js:

```js
...

function err(elem, msg) {
    if (msg) alert(msg);
    // start the transition
    elem.classList.add('error');
    elem.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        // 1 second later, remove the `error` class.
        elem.classList.add('no_transition');
        elem.classList.remove('error');
        elem.disabled = false;
        elem.classList.remove('no_transition'); // this is what triggers the `fade-in` animation again
    }, 1000);
}

...
```

Since adding / removing a class will trigger the CSS animation, I tried creating a separate class (`no-transition`) that blocks all animations and transitions. However, once I remove it, `fade-in` triggers once again.

Is there a way to work around this, and add / remove these CSS classes without triggering the `fade-in` animation?

Comment: [Animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) might be relevant here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your `animation` so that it contains the two sets of animations, this way the first one wouldn't restart:

```js
document.querySelector(".splash").addEventListener("click", ({
  target: elem,
  currentTarget
}) => {
  if (elem === currentTarget) {
    return;
  }
  elem.classList.add('error');
  setTimeout(() => {
    // 1 second later, remove the `error` class.
    elem.classList.remove('error');
  }, 1000);
})
console.log("click on either element to trigger the .error class");
```

```css
.splash * {
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: fade-in 1s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.error {
  /* Also set the fade-in class */
  animation: fade-in 1s ease-in, shake 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border-color: red;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <div>
    foo
  </div>
  <div>
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

But that implies the `fade-in` animation is always active when the `shake` one is.

So it actually sounds like you don't want  `fade-in` to be an animation, but a transition instead. If you have trouble making it kick when appending your elements, then see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134528/css-transition-doesnt-start-callback-isnt-called/55137322#55137322). Basically, you have to wait for (or force) a reflow before you set the target of the animation.

```js
// Wait for next browser reflow
const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  observer.disconnect();
  document.querySelector(".splash").classList.add("in");
});
observer.observe(document.body);

document.querySelector(".splash").addEventListener("click", ({
  target: elem,
  currentTarget
}) => {
  if (elem === currentTarget) {
    return;
  }
  elem.classList.add('error');
  setTimeout(() => {
    // 1 second later, remove the `error` class.
    elem.classList.remove('error');
  }, 1000);
})
console.log("click on either element to trigger the .error class");
```

```css
.splash * {
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}

.splash.in * {
  opacity: 1;
}

.error {
  animation: shake 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border-color: red;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <div>
    foo
  </div>
  <div>
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

But, since you're gonna use JS to control these transitions and animations, then it's even better to use the [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) to control these directly rather than do a complex round-trip through DOM then CSSOM.

```js
// fade-in all children at page load
document.querySelectorAll(".splash *").forEach((elem) => {
  elem.animate([{ opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1 }], { duration: 1000 });
});
// shake on click
document.querySelector(".splash").addEventListener("click", ({target: elem, currentTarget}) => {
  if (elem === currentTarget) { return; }
  elem.animate([
    { transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { transform: "translateX(-5px)" },
    { transform: "translateX(5px)" },
    { transform: "translateX(-5px)" },
    { transform: "translateX(0px)" },
  ], { duration: 400 });
  // We can even use it for non animated temporary styles like the 1s border-color
  elem.animate([{ borderColor: "red" }, { borderColor: "red" }], { duration: 1000 })
  // .finished.then(() => { the animation is over });
  // If you want to do something after the animation is over
})
console.log("click on either element to trigger the .error class");
```

```css
.splash * {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <div>
    foo
  </div>
  <div>
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the class when removing it by setting the opacity attribute from JavaScript:

```
elem.style.opacity = 0;
```

Another thing to try is by adding "!important" to force "animation: none" to be applied, or some other way to highen the specificity.

```
.no_transition {
    animation: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

You can also override the opacity in .no_transition:

```
.no_transition {
    animation: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

But you should of course try using CSS specificity over !important.

Comment: For tip #2 (and I believe #3), I don't believe that would help, since even if I delay the removal of `no_transition`, it will still trigger the animation after that delay, but up until that point, the animation is not triggered, so the `no_transition` class is working, but as soon as it's removed, the problem returns.