# Why does setting CSS property using Promise.then not actually happen at the then block?

Tags: javascript, css, promise, settimeout

Please try and run the following snippet, then click on the box.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')
box.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!box.style.transform) {
    box.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        box.style.transition = 'none'
        box.style.transform = ''
        resolve('Transition complete')
      }, 2000)
    }).then(() => {
      box.style.transition = ''
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box"></div>
```

What I expect to happen:

- Click happens
- Box starts translating horizontally by 100px (this action takes two seconds)
- On click, a new `Promise` is also created. Inside said `Promise`, a `setTimeout` function is set to 2 seconds
- After the action is completed (two seconds have elapsed), `setTimeout` runs its callback function and set `transition` to none. After doing that, `setTimeout` also reverts `transform` to its original value, thus rendering the box to appear at the original location.
- The box appears at the original location with no transition effect **problem here**
- After all of those finish, set the `transition` value of the box back to its original value

However, as can be seen, the `transition` value does not seem to be `none` when running. I know that there are other methods to achieve the above, e.g. using keyframe and `transitionend`, but why does this happen? I explicitly set the `transition` back to its original value only **after** the `setTimeout` finishes its callback, thus resolving the Promise.

**EDIT**

As per request, here's a gif of the code displaying the problematic behaviour:
[image: Problem]

Comment: In what browser are you seeing this? On Chrome, I am seeing what it is intended.

Comment: @Terry Firefox 73.0 (64-bit) for Windows.

Comment: Can you attach a gif to your question that illustrates the issue? As far as I could tell it's also rendering/behaving as expected on Firefox.

Comment: When the Promise resolves, the original transition is restored, but at this point the box is still transformed. Therefore it transitions back. You need to wait at least 1 more frame before resetting the transition to the original value: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3mjwtack/

Comment: When run multiple times, I managed to reproduce the problem once. Transition execution depends on what the computer is doing at background. Adding some more time to the delay before resolving the promise might help.

Comment: @Terry Added a gif displaying the problem.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you for the suggestion. However, I'm more interested in why this is happening.

Comment: Did you not see my comment from 5 minutes ago containing the explanation and solution...?

Comment: But I just explained it, transitions are not accurate, the execution time is depended on what the computer does on the background. That's why you're most often adviced to use animations instead.

Comment: @ChrisG But shouldn't it happen sequentially? In my code, setting `transform` value to its original value happened before tampering with the `transition` value.

Comment: In theory yes, but JS has a pretty complex internal event loop and some commands are not executed right away. They end up queued until the next frame. I've seen issues resolved by putting the code in question in `setTimeout` with a delay of zero.

Comment: @ChrisG I see. I suppose that an answer that explains the internal event loop briefly and a simple scenario of my commands being queued instead of being executed sequentially should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event loop *batches* style changes. If you change the style of an element on one line, the browser doesn't show that change immediately; it'll wait until the next animation frame. This is why, for example

```
elm.style.width = '10px';
elm.style.width = '100px';
```

doesn't result in flickering; the browser only cares about the style values set after all Javascript has completed.

Rendering occurs *after* all Javascript has completed, *including microtasks*. The `.then` of a Promise occurs in a microtask (which will effectively run as soon as all other Javascript has finished, but before anything else - such as rendering - has had a chance to run).

What you're doing is you're setting the `transition` property to `''` in the microtask, before the browser has started rendering the change caused by `style.transform = ''`.

If you reset the transition to the empty string after a `requestAnimationFrame` (which will run just before the next repaint), and then after a `setTimeout` (which will run just after the next repaint), it'll work as expected:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')
box.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!box.style.transform) {
    box.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
    setTimeout(() => {
      box.style.transition = 'none'
      box.style.transform = ''
      // resolve('Transition complete')
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          box.style.transition = ''
        });
      });
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks. Could you, perhaps, provide a link that describes these *microtask* and *repaint* mechanics?

Comment: This looks like a good summary: https://javascript.info/event-loop

Comment: That's not exactly true no. The event loop doesn't say anything about style changes. Most browsers will try to wait for the next painting frame when they can, but that's about it. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199904/3702797) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are facing a variation of the [*transition doesn't work if element start hidden*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348963/3702797) problem, but directly on the `transition` property.

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342730/javascript-are-dom-redraw-methods-synchronous/47343090#47343090) to understand how the CSSOM and the DOM are linked for the "redraw" process.
Basically, browsers will generally wait until the next [painting frame](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) to recalculate all the new box positions and thus to apply CSS rules to the CSSOM.

So in your Promise handler, when you reset the `transition` to `""`, the `transform: ""` has still not been calculated yet. When it will get calculated, the `transition` will already have been reset to `""` and the CSSOM will trigger the transition for the transform update.

However, we can [force the browser to trigger a "reflow"](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) and thus we can make it recalculate the position of your element, before we reset the transition to `""`.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')
box.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!box.style.transform) {
    box.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        box.style.transition = 'none'
        box.style.transform = ''
        box.offsetWidth; // this triggers a reflow
        resolve('Transition complete')
      }, 2000)
    }).then(() => {
      box.style.transition = ''
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box"></div>
```

Which makes the use of the Promise quite unnecessary:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')
box.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!box.style.transform) {
    box.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
    setTimeout(() => {
      box.style.transition = 'none'
      box.style.transform = ''
      box.offsetWidth; // this triggers a reflow
      // even synchronously
      box.style.transition = ''
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box"></div>
```

---

And for an explanation on micro-tasks, like `Promise.resolve()` or *MutationEvents*, or `queueMicrotask()`, you need to understand they'll get ran as soon as the current task is done, [7th step of the Event-loop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:perform-a-microtask-checkpoint), before [the rendering steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering).
So in your case, it's very like if it were ran synchronously.

By the way, beware micro-tasks can be as blocking as a while loop:

```
// this will freeze your page just like a while(1) loop
const makeProm = ()=> Promise.resolve().then( makeProm );
```

Comment: Yes exactly, but responding to the `transitionend` event would avoid having to hard-code a timeout to match the end of the transition. [transitionToPromise.js](https://gist.github.com/davej/44e3bbec414ed4665220) will promisify the transition allowing you to write `transitionToPromise(box, 'transform', 'translateX(100px)').then(() => /* four lines as per answer above */)`.

Comment: Two advantages: (1) the transition's duration can then be modified in CSS without needing to modify the javascript; (2) transitionToPromise.js is reusable. BTW, I tried it and it works well.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes you could, though I would personally add a check `(evt)=>if(evt.propertyName === "transform"){ ...` to avoid false positives and I don't really like promisifying such events, because you never know if it will ever fire (think of a case like  `someAncestor.hide() ` when the transition runs, your Promise will never fire and your transition will get stuck disabled. So that's really up to OP to determine what's best for them, but personally and by experience, I now prefer timeouts than transitionend events.

Comment: Pros & cons, I guess. In any case, with or without promisification, this answer is far cleaner than one involving two setTimeouts and a requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: I have one question though. You said that `requestAnimationFrame()` will be triggered **just before** the next browser repaint. You also mentioned that *browsers will generally wait until the next painting frame to recalculate all the new box positions*. Yet, you still needed to manually trigger a forced reflow (your answer on the first link). I, hence, draw the conclusion that even when `requestAnimationFrame()` happens just before repaint, the browser still has **not** calculated the newest computed style; thus, the need to **manually** force a recalculation of styles. Correct?

Comment: @Richard I did link to the event loop processing model at multiple occasions in my answer. From there you can see that only in some of these loops (or "frames") the [*update the rendering*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) algorithm is called (which makes this particular loop a "painting frame"). This frame is responsible for triggering a bunch of UI events, then requestAnimationFrame callbacks and finally update the rendering. If nothing required a synchronous reflow, then browsers will wait this very last step to recalc the box positions.

Comment: In other words, the *update the rendering* (recalculating box positions) step from "painting frame"  happens after said `requestAnimationFrame()` if synchronous reflow is not needed before this step?

Comment: @Richard requestAnimationFrame callbacks are called as part of the *update the rendering* algorithm (10.11). So is the actual *rendering* (10.14). It is not specced here when the recalculating of box positions happens. But since it's a costly operation, browsers will try to wait the last moment to do it. This last moment is **inside** the final "rendering" step (10.14). At this time no user-script (js) is to be ran anymore on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is just that in your `.then` you are setting the `transition` to `''`, when you should be setting it to `none` as you did in the timer callback.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
box.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!box.style.transform) {
    box.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)';
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        box.style.transition = 'none';
        box.style.transform = '';
        resolve('Transition complete');
      }, 2000)
    }).then(() => {
     box.style.transition = 'none'; // <<----
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box"></div>
```

Comment: No, OP is setting it to `''` to apply the class rule again (which was overruled by the element rule) your code simply sets it to `'none'` twice, which prevents the box from transitioning back but doesn't restore its original transition (the class's)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this isn't quite what you're looking for, but - out of curiosity and for the sake of completeness - I wanted to see if I could write a CSS-only approach to this effect.

*Almost*... but it turns out I still had to include a single line of javascript.

**Working Example:**

```js
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('animationend', (e) => e.target.blur());
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #121212;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:focus {
 animation: boxAnimation 2s ease;
}

@keyframes boxAnimation {
  100% {transform: translateX(100px);}
}
```

```html
<div class="box" tabindex="0"></div>
```