# Changing element display and setting transition after requestAnimationCallback not working when triggered by transitionEnd event

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

There are several StackOverflow posts about why changing an element's `display` from 'none' to 'box/flex/etc.' and making a CSS transition kick-in doesn't work.
The suggested solution, which makes sense, is to use `requestAnimationFrame` to make the CSS transition kick-in after the reflow.

One answer with a good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348963/16741294).

I've come across an interesting case where that doesn't work: when doing so in a 'transitionend' callback. Somehow, the `requestAnimationFrame` isn't enough in this case.

Quick setup:
A blue and red box. Blue box is faded in with this technique and it works. On blue box's `transitionend`, it is hidden and we use the same technique to show the red box. The red box shows instantly instead of fading in/having the opacity transition.
Also, added an `onClick` for the red box to redo the transition in the same manner - and it works.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("elem");
let elem2 = document.getElementById("elem2");

function addFadeElem2() {
  elem2.classList.add("fade");
}

function switchElements() {
    elem.classList.remove("fade") ;
    elem2.style.display = "block";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(addFadeElem2);
}

elem.style.display = "block";
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  elem.classList.add("fade");
});

function onTransitionEnd() {
  switchElements();
  //elem.offsetHeight; // Works with forced reflow
  elem.removeEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionEnd);
}

elem.addEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionEnd);

function refade() {
  elem2.style.display = "none";
  elem2.classList.remove("fade");
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() =>
  {
    elem2.style.display = "block";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(addFadeElem2);
  });
}
```

```css
#elem {
  background-color: blue;
}

#elem2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  opacity : 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.box.fade {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem" class="box">aaaaa</div>
<div id="elem2" class="box" onclick="refade()">bbbbbbb</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/johnnyfang/pen/rNwNyeZ)

If I force a reflow with offsetHeight, it works as expected. (of course if this was executed right after setting `display: block`, there is no longer a need for the `requestAnimationFrame` at all).
Likewise, "double-`requestAnimationFrame`ing" also works.

Here are screenshots from devtools profiling:

[Showing blue box / initial page load, transition works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMJ1g.png)

[Switch to showing red box, transition doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbKOl.png)

Noticeably when the transition doesn't work, the `requestAnimationFrame` callback occurs before there was a reflow with only `display: box` taken into account.
But why is that the case after a transitionend event and/or why is that not the case during page load or onClick? (Is the onClick a valid example of the technique working, or is it tainted by the `display: block` being set in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback).

I'm either missing or misunderstanding some fundementals.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the transtionend events are fired right before the animation frame callbacks.

If you look at the event loop's processing model's ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) steps, you'll see that (currently), the step #10 reads

> For each fully active Document in docs, update animations and send events for that Document, passing in now as the timestamp.

That's where the *transitionend* events will get fired.

And just a couple of steps below, #13 is

> For each fully active Document in docs, run the animation frame callbacks for that Document, passing in now as the timestamp.

So, as I explained in that answer you linked to, when using `requestAnimationFrame`, the UA *may* have updated the layout if it deemed it had time in between your call and the actual execution of the callback.
This *may* be true for instance if you do call `requestAnimationFrame` at the beginning of the "frame", so that it schedules far in the future.

However, when calling `requestAnimationFrame()` from a *transitionend* event, you actually scheduled your callback to fire right after, if you don't have a resize callback, it will literally fire synchronously:

```js
ontransitionend = (evt) => {
  const t1 = performance.now();
  const t2 = performance.now();
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    const t3 = performance.now();
    console.log("synchronous elapsed: %sms", t2 - t1);
    console.log("rAF elapsed: %sms", t3 - t2);
  });
};
document.body.offsetLeft; // trigger a reflow for our transition to kick in ;)
document.body.style.opacity = 1;
```

```css
body {
  transition: opacity .1s;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

And in such a short time you can be pretty sure the browser won't have triggered automatically a reflow.

So at the risk of repeating myself, to ensure that a reflow did occur and that your transition will kick in, force the reflow yourself, using one of these: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: Thank you so much for the (2nd) detailed response, @Kaiido.

To make sure I'm following: in layman's terms, my assumption that changing `display` will necessarily cause a layout update before the `requestAnimationFrame` callback was incorrect.
Depending on when the `display` (or any layout-affecting) change occurs, it may not effect for the upcoming paint.
An for `transitionend` specifically, it is so close to when the `requestAnimationFrame` callback occurs that it is likely (for me, empirically - deterministic) the layout will not be updated in-between.

Comment: The change of the display rule will have effect at least during the painting, which happens a few steps after in [my link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) (substep #16). But rAF callbacks are fired before that painting.