# AngularJs - how to detect tap event in mobile without using ng-touch or ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The below code is detecting `click` in desktop but in mobile the `touch` event gets triggered when trying to scroll over the element,how to prevent this `touch` event and only detect `tap` events.I am not allowed to use `ng-touch` or `ng-click`.
I have tried the below approaches but these dont seem to work.What changes need to be made in below code?

[What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

[onClick not working on mobile (touch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch)

[What is the most reliable way to detect clicks (or touches) on both desktop and mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337994/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-detect-clicks-or-touches-on-both-desktop-and)

```
(function() {
    'user strict';
    angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective',function(){
    return{
    restrict:'A',
    scope:{
    id: '=myId',
    pm: '=myPm'
    },
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.on('click touchend',funtion(event){
        console.log("clicked");
        });
    }


    }:
    });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

use onclick="myFunction()" or use ng-click
it'll work for sure
in HTML--
ng-click="xyz(params)"
like below shown::

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ng-click in AngularJs</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('ngClickCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            $scope.domain = "stackoverflow.com";
            $scope.IsDisplay = false;
            $scope.clickMe = function (clicked) {
                    alert(" My Click function is called.");
                $scope.IsDisplay = clicked == true ? false : true;
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ngClickCtrl">
        <div><h2>ng-click in AngularJs</h2> </div>
        <div>
            Domain name: <input type="text" ng-model="domain"> <button type="button" ng-click="clickMe(IsDisplay)">NG-CLICK</button>   
        </div>
        <div>
            <div ng-show="IsDisplay"> My Click function is called. <br /><h3 style="color:green;">testing ng-click events: {{domain}} </h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am not allowed to use `ng-click` as well,i want to create a custom directive.I have edited my question and have included this.

Comment: use onclick="myFunction()"