# Why does Google Chrome ignore the opacity of children of elements with initial display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, dom

There are `div` elements with child `p` elements that repeatedly go from hidden to shown states. Both `display` and `opacity` attributes are used for this. The `opacity` attribute has a 1 second transition time.

The cycle is as follows:

1. Change `display: none` to `display: initial`
2. Wait 50 milliseconds for [document reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269614/why-does-reflow-need-to-be-triggered-for-css-transitions) (which [should happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow) on its own)
3. Change `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`
4. Wait 2 seconds
5. Change `opacity: 1` to `opacity: 0`
6. Wait 1 second for transition to finish
7. Change `display: initial` to `display: none`
8. Wait 1 second
9. Repeat

This works perfectly fine in FireFox, but in Google Chrome it only works in certain cases, demonstrated in the code snippet.

- In the simple case it doesn't work.
- If the child `p` is set to `inline-block` it works.
- If the `inline-block` element is a grandchild instead of a child it doesn't work.
- If the position of the child is set to `fixed` it works.

The curious thing is that the transition in step 5 also fails, which has nothing to do with the `display` attribute, so this does not seem to be due to reflow failures.

```js
var flag = true;
var elements;

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
    cycleQuotes();
    setInterval(cycleQuotes, 2000);
}

function cycleQuotes() {
    if(flag) {
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.display = "initial";
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].style.opacity = 1;
            }
        },50);
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.opacity = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        },1000);
    }
    flag = !flag;
}
```

```css
.foo {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}

#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <p>normal</p>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <p class="inline-block">inline-block</p>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div>
    <p class="inline-block">inline-block but grandchild</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <p id="fixed">fixed</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to isolate the issue outside of the animation. For some reason I don't understand, Google Chrome doesn't propagate opacity to children of an element with `display: initial`.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  display: initial;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  text inside div
  <p>text inside paragraph</p>
</div>
```

On Firefox you see nothing, on Chrome you see `text inside paragraph` and nothing else. Very odd.

Comment: ...unless the child is `inline-block` or has a `position: fixed` (and probably some other cases too). Nice find in either case; this is probably a big piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Gendarme Another fix is to put the opacity and the display styles on different wrappers. That seems to work too.

Answer (score 0):

@jacquegoupil discovered that this is caused by the combination of `display: initial` and the `opacity` attribute.

Further research brought me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851838/5221346) which states that `initial` does not mean *"default"*, meaning that it does not set the value of the attribute to the one that is default for the element. What it does it to set the attribute to the value that it defined as *"initial"* in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop). In the case of the `display` attribute, `initial` means `inline`.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Conceptual_differences), inline elements cannot contain block elements, and since `p` elements have `display: block` by default.

Comment: The HTML in the question is not invalid. MDN's description there is based on an archaic definition of "inline" and "block" that blurs the line between HTML and CSS. While it is not possible for a block box to be contained within an inline box, 1) [CSS contains provisions for that sort of situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290281/what-goes-wrong-when-a-displayinline-custom-element-contains-displayblock-elem/24000067#24000067) 2) it doesn't change the nature of the HTML elements and therefore does not affect the validity of the HTML.

Comment: So it is a bug in Google Chrome, then? @BoltClock

Comment: I suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642290/ie-offsetting-and-ignoring-height-width-of-anchor-focus-outlines/23644188#23644188) sort of answers the question.

Comment: [Looks like it.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=764011) This used to affect Firefox as well [once upon a time](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660682), additional discussion [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1399527). Not sure if the underlying cause in Chrome is related for both cases.